# Problem with my app delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I am trying to make an app that contains a class that is created in the app delegate.
I initialize it with:

```
    Mobile *tmp = [[Mobile alloc] init];
    mobile = tmp;
    [tmp release];
```

and then I try to use it in other classes in my app with this:

```
    projectAppDelegate *delegate = (projectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    mobile = delegate.mobile;
```

but when I do something like:

```
[mobile enter:x :y];
```

it crashes...

Is there something I did wrong, or is there any solution for making a class that all the other classes in the app can use?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the signature for the "enter" method? You seem to be missing a parameter name.

Comment: he didnt enter the enter method because mobile is nil. there is something i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use instances of your object you have to store them as properties of app delegate.

```
//appdelegate.h
//
//...
//
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
  Mobile *tmp;
}
//...

//appdelegate.m
//
//...
//
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  mobile = [[Mobile alloc]init];      
}
//...
-  (void)dealloc {
  [mobile release];
  [super dealloc];
//...
}
```

Than you have to get a pointer to your application delegate shared instance and call your `mobile` property.

```
//... Somewhere
AppDelegate* ref = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%@", [ref mobile]);
//...
```

Comment: thank you.i try to call a method that i have in the Mobile class from another class with this:
`projectAppDelegate *delegate = (projectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 Mobile *mobile = delegate.mobile;
 [mobile enter:x :y];`

and he didn't jump to this method,you maybe know why?

Comment: you maybe have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet you are effectively creating and immediately destroying the object. If the object is supposed to persist after that method is done executing you should just use

```
mobile = [[Mobile alloc] init];
```

Comment: thank you.i try to call a method that i have in the Mobile class from another class with this:
`projectAppDelegate *delegate = (projectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 Mobile *mobile = delegate.mobile;
 [mobile enter:x :y];`

and he didn't jump to this method,you maybe know why?